# Проблема not function с callback

Tags: node.js

Почему возникает ошибка: "objectForImage is not function"? Разве я не могу функцию передавать как объект? Если пример ещё более простым делать, то callback без проблем вызывается.

```
function loadSprite(dir, objectForImage) {
    var list_block_image = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    var file_name = randomElement(list_block_image);
    jimp.read(dir+file_name, function (err, load_image) { if (err) throw err; objectForImage (load_image);});

}

loadSprite("./boys/", function (image_load) {boysSprite=image_load;});
```

Comment: чтобы получить function вы должны вызвать функцию или возвращать  фанктор, а  objectForImage (load_image) это ни то и ни другое

Comment: objectForImage (load_image); - вот так разве я не вызываю функцию? можете более подробно объяснить.

Comment: это все тело функции loadSprite? objectForImage нигде не переопределяется?

Comment: И вы уверены, что при вызове loadSprite передается вторым аргументом именно функция? Может быть значение подставляется динамически, и приходит не то, что нужно?

Comment: Да, да. До строчки jimp.read. Лог показывает [function: objectForImage].

Comment: Кстати, без параметра image_load функций отрабатывает нормально. Что-то я вообще уже ничего не понимаю.

Comment: @hitcode в будущем упоминайте при помощи символа `@`, чтобы участник получил уведомление

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. У меня было подряд несколько вызовов:

```
loadSprite("./boys/", function (image_load) {boysSprite=image_load;});
loadSprite("./bombs/", old_value);
loadSprite("./bonus/", old_value);
```

И крашилось не на строчке 1, она отрабатывала идеально. А на последующих строчках.

Всем спасибо за помощь.